# why status bar behaves differently - swift

Tags: ios, statusbar

I'm using a tabbar controller and in each tab, I have a uiview controller embedded in a navigation controller. in each view of mt view controllers, I have a scroll view. everything is the same but when I run it, I get different appears for status bar. why is this happening?

first tab:

[image]

second tab: 
[image]

notice the white background color in second tab that does not exist in first tab. What causes sth like this?

Comment: Can you show a bit more of how you set up your navigation- and viewcontrollers?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I updated the post

Comment: @Hos Ap it would be much helpful if you show storyboard image where you have view controller.